# Segmentation violation on symfony 2.6.6 process component

Tags: symfony, processbuilder, symfony-2.6, symfony-process

When I try to run a command on a sub-process created by ProcessBuilder, i get segmentation violation.

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]  
The process has been signaled with signal "11".
```

But this doesn't happen upto v2.5.12 only from v2.6.0

Comment: Did you check this? https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2146

Comment: no luck yet. tried all suggestions so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally the issue is found. Thanks to Rackspace support staff Cristian Banciu and Mike Bostic

Cause:

Latest newrelic php agent 4.23.1.107 causes seg fault when used with symfony 2.6.0 or above with process component.
newrelic.browser_monitoring.auto_instrument = 0 didn't help

Solution:

finally i downgraded newrelic php agent to 4.21.0.97-1 and all work fine

Anojan